# Looped SQL query

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, loops, average

I'm working on a home weather station based on `RaspberryPi`. Currently I'm working on displaying a table with average temperatures in last few days. I got it working this way:
The data is stored in `SQLite3` database, and the pages are generated with PHP.
I'm doing a loop in PHP to get average temperature in every period, and in every PHP loop cycle I'm doing a SQL Query, changing values of `$starttime` and `$endtime`:

```
SELECT avg(t1),avg(t2) FROM temperatures WHERE time_stamp 
    BETWEEN $starttime AND $endtime
```

It works ok but the performance is poor due to multiple SQL queries (30 secs page generation time when displaying week's data with 4 values per day; and only 5 secs when there is 1 value per day).

Can I somehow write a single SQL query that will do all the work without that loop in PHP?

Edit:
PHP Code:

```
        $db = new SQLite3('/home/pi/temperature.db');


    for ($i = $INTERVAL; $i <= $PERIOD; $i+=$INTERVAL)
    {
            $starttime = sprintf("datetime('now','-%d minutes')", $i-$INTERVAL);
            $endtime   = sprintf("datetime('now','-%d minutes')", $i);

            $sqlquery  = "SELECT avg(t1),avg(t2) FROM temperatura where ts_utc between ".$endtime." and ".$starttime.";";

            $sqlresult = $db->query($sqlquery);

            $row = $sqlresult->fetchArray();

            $starttime = sprintf("datetime('now','-%d minutes','localtime')", $i-$INTERVAL);
            $endtime   = sprintf("datetime('now','-%d minutes','localtime')", $i);


            $sqlquery = 'select strftime("%H:%M",'.$starttime.");";
            $sqlresult = $db->query($sqlquery);
            $starttime = $sqlresult->fetchArray();

            $sqlquery = 'select strftime("%H:%M",'.$endtime.");";
            $sqlresult = $db->query($sqlquery);
            $endtime = $sqlresult->fetchArray();

            echo $endtime[0]."-".$starttime[0];
            echo sprintf("  %2.1f",($row["avg(t1)"]/1000))."&deg;C    ".sprintf("%2.1f",($row["avg(t2)"]/1000))."&deg;C<br>";
    }
```

timestamp (ts) field is datetime type

Comment: Can you show your PHP code?

Comment: So you want the average per day over the last n days in one go?

Comment: Oh and what type is time_stamp?

Comment: @Tony Hopkins, let's say I want to get 12 averages per day in a week.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a single query with `UNION`, but I'm pretty sure the quantity of request is not the issue here, 5 sec for one request is way too slow

I would

1. ensure there is an index on timestamp
2. check if index makes things better (`EXPLAIN` on the query might help)
3. if still slow, fetch all required data and compute average with PHP

Comment: 5 secs is for 7 requests (each for every day). I'll check out UNION and index and see how it goes.

Comment: From your edit and the code you posted, you can format time without a sql request!

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming ts_utc is a date time, something like

```
Select avg(t1) as t1_avg, avg(t2) as t2_avg, 
Date(ts_utc) as measurement_Date, 
Cast((Hour(ts_utc) / 2) as int) as measurement_Hour 
From temperatura
Group by Date(ts_utc),Cast((Hour(ts_utc) / 2) as int)
Where ts_utc >= Date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 7 days)
```

NB not checked for sillies. especially mysql specific ones...